# Converting Geography data type column to a NVARCHAR

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column in my database of data type Geography which I want to convert to a varchar.

I am using the following query to make do this ...

-- 1: Issue with Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

```
ALTER TABLE RetailerStore ALTER COLUMN Location VARCHAR(50)
```

However, I get the error message

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Implicit conversion from data type geography to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Has anybody come across this and if so do they know a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion.  Is there data in the column?  If so, set it all to NULL before attempting to change the column type.  Alternatively, you can drop and recreate the column.

Note that there is an explicit conversion from geography to a text form - you can use the [STAsText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933970.aspx) to convert the spatial type to a text representation.

Using [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) to DROP and ADD:

```
ALTER TABLE RetailerStore DROP COLUMN Location;
ALTER TABLE RetailerStore ADD Location VARCHAR(50) NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Cade, the whole column is set to null.

Would you be able to help me detail the tsql statement to drop the column and then re-create it please.

Thanks

Comment: @swade1987 Maybe all NULLs doesn't work because geography is a CLR type.  I added the DROP and ADD example to my answer.

Comment: ADD didn't require the word COLUMN but everything else was fine, cheers dude.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the column from your table first:

```
ALTER TABLE RetailerStore DROP COLUMN Location;
```

And then add that column again with the desired datatype and range like given below:

```
ALTER TABLE RetailerStore ADD Location VARCHAR(100) NULL;
```